# How to alter the height of the right divs in a 2x2 grid?

Tags: html, css

I have a 2x2 grid using this HTML and CSS:

```html
<div className="gameScreen">
      <GameTable 
        seats={seats}
      />

      <ChatBox socket={socket} username={username} />

      <InfoTable numPlayers={numPlayers} seats={seats} timer={false}/>

      <GameCommands gameMasterSpeech={gameMasterSpeech}/>
    </div>
```

```css
.gameScreen {
  display: grid; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 4fr 1fr;
}
```

It creates a 2x2 grid where:

- first grid is 3fr wide and 4fr tall
- second grid is 2fr wide and 4fr tall
- third grid is 3fr wide and 1fr tall
- fourth grid is 2fr wide and 1fr tall.

I want the second grid to be shorter, about 3fr, and the fourth grid to be 2fr. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after a while:

```css
.gameScreen {
  display: grid; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.gameScreen .left {
  display: grid; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 3.5fr 1fr;
}

.gameScreen .right {
  display: grid; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 3fr 2fr;
}
```

```html
<div className="gameScreen">
      <div className="left">
        <GameTable/>
        <InfoTable/>
      </div>
      <div className="right">
        <ChatBox />
        <GameCommands />
      </div>
    </div>
```